# angular material md.data.table pagination issue

Tags: angularjs, datatable, pagination, angular-material

I'm using the md.data.table to display data that I get from the backend,
there is a lot of data (~40000 row) so I'm using backend pagination like this:
in the fist time I get 100 row from the backend so with a limit of 10, the user can navigate in the first 10 pages, when he ask for a page in [11,20](for example) a new request is sent to get the newt 100 rows, and so on.
my problem is that when I get a new 100 rows from the backend (for example the user select the 11th page) I get the result but **the page number return to 1** I tried to set it manually using : `paginationParams.page=11` but it doesn't work
can anyone help.
thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you share some code/markup or an online example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the solution my self, and here is the solution for those who will have the same issue 
the problem was that when I send the request the get the next 100 rows, I copy it in the variable used to show the first 100 rows.
so the solution is, instead of copy the result in the variable, I add them to it, and that solve the problem